# Can someone help me with this Powershell error

Tags: powershell

```
fuction : The term 'fuction' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Powershell\Powershell1.ps1:1 char:1
+ fuction pc {
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (fuction:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Maybe a typo **function** instead of `fuction` ?

Comment: As you have essentially posted the same thing as an answer: you are missing an "n" in the word "function" in whatever script you are writing. You have "fuction" where you should have "fu**n**ction"

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo error in your PowerShell code. You typed *fuction* instead of [*function*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7) which is a PowerShell keyword.

PowerShell function usage example:

```
function Get-PowerShellProcess { Get-Process PowerShell }
```